# How long have parenthesis (brackets) been used?

Tags: notation

If you look at a work such as Bertrand Russel's Principia Mathematica there are no brackets at all. So are brackets a recent invention?

Newton used to draw a line above long expressions to group terms. (We still use this notation for things like roots).

How long have they been used?

When was the first time parenthesis have been used in mathematical expressions?

Comment: Parentheses, brackets and braces go back to 16th century, see [Jeff Miller's Earliest Uses](https://jeff560.tripod.com/grouping.html), vinculum and other grouping symbols are dated there too. Dot notation instead of parentheses in Russell's *Principia* was abnormal and only spread in logic, not mathematics, see [Who superseded Peano's dot notation in symbolic logic and when?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/11605/55)